# How to get the CSV headers of an S3 Object without downloading entire file?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, csv, object, amazon-s3

I have a very large CSV file in S3, and just need to get the headers of that file (the top row of a CSV that has column names, not HTTP headers). Is there a way to do this without downloading the entire file first? I'm using the Java AWS SDK. I don't think this information is stored in the object metadata, but I may be wrong.

Edit:

The chosen answer below worked, and it used S3 Select, but the query that worked for me was

```
select s.* from S3Object s limit 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `S3 select` to query the data from any file stored in **AWS S3**.

Java example for the same from [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SelectObjectContentUsingJava.html).

To select the **column headers** from a `CSV` file, you can `limit` the results to `one record`. Check here for [SELECT command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html).

For example:

```
QUERY = "select s.* from S3Object s limit 1";
```

Check for [different type of query examples here](https://towardsdatascience.com/ditch-the-database-20a5a0a1fb72).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use this with Java SDK? I searched for one but wasn't able to find.

Edit: Actually nvm found it here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/SelectObjectContentUsingJava.html

Comment: The example in docs posted in answer is for Java SDK only (Selecting content from objects using the SDK for Java)

Comment: Thanks for updating the query. Updated my answer with the same.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you can download a range of bytes from the files. So then you can download let's say maybe 10% of the file ( but you'll have to figure out this number by yourself ) and then transform those bytes into chars, then strings.

The output will probably be the header + some values, so you'll have to see how you can parse the content so that you remain only with the header.

```
// Get a range of bytes from an object and print the bytes.
            GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key)
                    .withRange(0, 9);
```

Comment: some doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html

Comment: Thanks guys. Let me give this a shot and if it works, I'll mark this as accepted. This would definitely work for large files, so I might just use the object metadata to grab filesize, and if it's larger than a certain amount, then go with this method. If smaller, then I'll just download the entire file.